# Avoid HTML requests and make only js call - ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1, request, call

I'm developing a web app in Ruby-On-Rails. It heavily uses JavaScript. The problem is, when user clicks on a link which is suppose to make JS call and if the JavaScript is disabled or fails to load completely due to slow internet connection; it makes HTML request. This gives me error "Missing template". I don't want to redirect user to any HTML page template.

How can I disable link when JavaScript is turned off? or force to make only JS call? I want to implement something similar like Twitter.

Any help highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never want the link to actually process the href and go anywhere, then set the href for the link to `"#"` rather than a real URL.

Comment: hmm.. right.. but then how can I make JS call to the URL? should I specify that URL in a data attribute?

Comment: If you need data on the link, you can put it on some other attribute like a data attribute if you want.

Comment: thanks... I wonder how Twitter hide the URL! They never mention the URL. As if they construct the route in js.